# Stuck in bootloop. Login screen doesn't show up

Tags: gnome, login, plasma

I've recently decided to install `kde-plasma-desktop` Desktop environment, but it was laggy on my PC and so I decided to switch back to gnome. So I removed the `kde-plasma-desktop` package and other kde packages using synaptic's package manager GUI. Then I was unable to login with xorg, but I was able to login into Wayland just fine. Today, I booted up my laptop and it doesn't show up a login screen at all.

My guess is that `gdm3` cannot start, and that's what causing the issue. I'll attach my `journalctl -b` logs and `dmesg` logs below.

How do I fix it?

- `journalctl -b` log:

  https://pastebin.com/DwCCcn2J
- `dmesg` log

  https://pastebin.com/hgdwx4EG

Comment: I tried `nvidia-xconfig` and I was able to see the logon screen but I didn't logon after entering the password with a error message similar to "Oops! Something went wrong" and there was a logout button. I also tried `sudo X -configure` and I could see the logon screen but unable to use the mouse and keyboard. Finally I deiced to reinstall ubuntu with the flash drive without formatting the /home directory. Now the problem is solved. But I still don't know what caused the problem. I remember seeing something like "failed to load DRM" in /var/log/Xorg.0.log